# php mysql result after doing fetch_assoc() again

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php class file something like store mysql result to array:

```
<?php
class myclass{
    public $result_array;

    function __construct($result){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $this->result_array[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and in php page:

```
$obj = new myclass($result);
```

so far works fine, but then i try to fetch data from $result again like:

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ($row as $cell): ?>
        <td><?php echo $cell; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

then the fetch_assoc() part does not work, since i pass $result by value into constructor,
can't figure out why this happen, any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: `foreach($obj->result_array as $row)`

Comment: Why do this anyway? just iterate the $results_array

Comment: Think about why `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` ever *stops* in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have done `$result->fetch_assoc()` in the constructor, the pointer in the result set is now at the end and so any further calls will return `NULL`. Instead you should iterate your `result_array`:

```
<?php foreach($obj->result_array as $row): ?>
....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, `$result` is not being passed by value, it is a reference to the same object and is not a clone.

Comment: thanks for all the replies, i'm just confused by the document says php passing parameter by value as default, thank you for the answer.